# Javascript logic statement - I got 99 problems

Tags: javascript

...but a glitch ain't one.

Hey there, I am still learning so I apologize for the simple question. I'm just trying out a hypothetical logic statement that would still make sense using javascript.

Example:

```
if (problems == 99) {
glitch != 1
}
```

Basically, I'd like it to mean "If I have 99 problems, a glitch isn't one of them" in the shortest code I can muster. Any help is really appreciated!!

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you expect `glitch` to equal if `problems` is 99?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it appears to be a codegolf-like question (at best it's a codereview question).

Comment: I'd go with `99==problems&&(glitch=!1)`

Answer (score 1):

Even shorter

```
glitch = problems !== 99;
```

Here's a more lyrical version:

```
if (problems.length === 99 && problems.indexOf("glitch")=== -1){
    return "HOVA";
}
```

Comment: Why not use the `!==` operator?

Comment: The second example is very different logic to the first (ignoring the syntactic error of *return* outside a function), which could simply be `glitch = problems != 99`.

Comment: The second is very different, but it follows the logic of the song. The first does not.

Answer (score -1):

You are not setting glitch. Try `glitch = false` instead

Comment: Let's assume both 'glitch' and 'problems' are already set, is my code otherwise correct/proper?

Comment: No. Because your statement is a boolean and doesn't change the value of glitch